# what does question mark stand for in this function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn javascript and was going through this code. In the function `function range(start, end, step = start < end ? 1 : -1)`, what does `step = start < end ? 1 : -1` stand for?

```
function range(start, end, step = start < end ? 1 : -1) {
  let array = [];

  if (step > 0) {
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) array.push(i);
  } else {
    for (let i = start; i >= end; i += step) array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}

function sum(array) {
  let total = 0;
  for (let value of array) {
    total += value;
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(range(1, 10))
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
console.log(range(5, 2, -1));
// → [5, 4, 3, 2]
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
// → 55
```

Comment: It's the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It's used in a [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) expression, but otherwise it works exactly as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It basically means if `start < end` evaluates to true then assign `1` to step otherwise -1

This line step = start < end ? 1 : -1 can be written as

```
if(start < end){
 step=1;
}
else{
step=-1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means:

```
let step 
if(start < end) step=1
else step=-1
```